# Threadsafe test / decrement

Tags: multithreading, delphi, freepascal, lazarus

Is this code threadsafe, or could FCount be changed by another thread before InterLockedDecrement is executed?

```
procedure TMyObject.Wait;
begin
  if FCount > 0 then
    InterLockedDecrement(FCount);
  ..
end;
```

Comment: See the sourcecode of [SyncObjs.TCountdownEvent.Signal](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SyncObjs.TCountdownEvent.Signal) for an example of a threadsafe decrement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not thread-safe.

- Thread 1 reads FCount=1, evaluates condition to True.
- Thread 2 reads FCount=1, evaluates condition to True.
- Thread 1 decrements FCount to 0
- Thread 2 decrements FCount to -1

Yet I assume the code is specifically intended to prevent reducing `FCount` below zero.

You might want to consider the following instead:

```
if InterlockedDecrement(FCount) < 0 then
  InterlockedIncrement(FCount);
```

In this way, one of the two concurrent threads will reduce the value to -1 and then "fix its mistake".
However, it does have the side-effect that `FCount` may temporarily be `< 0`.

Comment: I see, the code is not threadsafe. Unfortunately, the code you suggest I vaguely suspect that after the call to InterlockedDecrement, it is possible for another thread to either read or change the value of FCount before the correct value is assigned.

Comment: No. That's not it. The problem is that there's no synchronization on the read in the `if`.

Comment: So I should protect the read and increment with a critical section?

Comment: @Rimfire It depends on what you're trying to achieve and what the purpose of `FCount` is. My suggestion is based on the idea "incorrectly" reducing `FCount` is easily reversible. However, if you have other decision logic based that reads or modifies `FCount` you need to evaluate whether it will be a problem. You can do a step-by-step walkthrough of 2 threads as in my answer to help with the decision. But only you have the information to do so.

Comment: If my suggestion is not suitable, then some other synchronisation technique is needed. (A critical section is one possibility, but there are others.)

Comment: @Rimfire I don't see how you can ask us what you should do without presenting us with a problem.

Answer (score 5):

The code is not threadsafe. There is a race on the read of `FCount` in the `if` statement.

Since I don't know what your code is intended to achieve, what the greater goal is, I won't suggest a solution.

Answer (score 1):

It's not thread safe as others have pointed out. If you want to ensure that the code decreases the value of FCount if it's greater than 0 then you could use something like this without locking:

```
procedure TMyObject.Wait;
var
  count: Integer;
  countPlus1: Integer;
begin
  repeat
    count := FCount;
    if (count > 0) then
    begin
      countPlus1 := count; 
      Dec(count);
    end;
  until (count <= 0) or (InterlockedCompareExchange(FCount, count, countPlus1) = countPlus1);
  ..
end;
```